# Remove a part of url address in Django

Tags: python, django, urlconf

I'm developing a multilingual web page.

url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
     url(r'^(?P<lang>\w{2})/$', 'mysite.views.home')
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

views.py

```
def home(request,lang='fa'):
    language_mapping = {'en': 'en', 'ar': 'ar'}
    selected_lang = language_mapping.get(lang, 'fa')
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'lang':selected_lang})
```

In my html I have some `<img>` tags

```
<img src="media/image.jpg" alt="">
```

The problem is if I run my address like `mysite.com`, I can see the image but address like these

```
mysite.com/fa/
mysite.com/en/
mysite.com/ar/
```

make my image goes away as it make my address like `mysite.com/en/media/image.jpg`

So How can I remove `/lang/` part from my address in `<img>` tags?

Something like this maybe?

```
url(r'^(?P<lang>\w{2})/media' = r'^/media/' )
```

I have no idea where to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You can change the `'media/img.jpg'` to `'/media/img.jpg'` (note the leading slash) to make it a root-relative url -- thus making it always request `mysite.com/media/img.jpg` instead of attaching the lang tag.
2. You can switch to using Django's [static file management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/) which is probably a better idea in the long run anyway.

Comment: I'm managing my static files with `nginx` and `gunicorn`.  And thank you. that `/` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use an absolute path in your HTML.

```
<img src="/media/image.jpg" alt="">
```

Note the leading slash.